# App permissions

Tags: sound, permissions, ubuntu-touch, application-development

I am developing a simple sound recorder using Qt Creator. It uses the QAudioRecorder class and Qml.

The app compiles and runs on the desktop during testing and I am able to play back the recorded sound. The app writes a file to the home directory

When I deploy it on my Ubuntu Aquarius 4.5 device, I am unable to write to the home folder (`/home/phablet`).

I changed the location to `/tmp`. I am able to see and play back the file there.

I also see `shm_open` errors.

My questions:

1. How do I get the app to write to the Music folder?
2. How do i get rid of the shm_open errors?